# Swing application UI modelling

Tags: java, swing, layout

I'm in the modelling phase of the UI of a Swing application. This application offers different stages of data processing. Each stage depends on the results given by the stage before. The different stages share no common widgets.

The card Layout is not a professionnal choice in my point of view. Do you know any other way to order widgets, or an example of a professionnal application dealing with that same issue?

Comment: How about JTabbedPane?

Comment: That sounds to me as a use case for a wizard: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/wizard-136789.html and here: https://github.com/bflorat/qdwizard

Comment: Since it must be a desktop application with MenuBar, Toolbar... I don't think a wizzard will be a good layout for my case. I'm thinking about something like perspectives, but I don't really see how to put that idea in my context.